# how to query the status of an apache flink web console [metrics api]

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Is there any URL that exporting a json file that describes the status of the of a flink cluster service?

I.e sys uptime, jobs status, number of nodes, etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should definitely have a look at the Monitoring REST API.

The documentation for that feature can be accessed [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.2/monitoring/rest_api.html)

You can also access some TaskManager metrics, unfortunately they are not yet described in the doc, but you can have a look at source-code: [WebRuntimeMonitor](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/release-1.2.0/flink-runtime-web/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/runtime/webmonitor/WebRuntimeMonitor.java)